# Is there a better way to pass in components using hooks? My solution is provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure how to phrase this question without it being multiple problems per this being closed.

This is my solution to passing in components via hooks and rendering them based on what link the user presses on. I'm putting the components as objects into an array and then using that array to map through the index which then makes this all very dynamic.

My only question is if there is a more effective way of achieving this and why? I'm still intermediate with Javascript so I'm trying to learn the most effective way to do something.

```
const switchArray = [
      {
        name: 'Step 1',
        Component: <Step1 />
      },
      {
        name: 'Step 2',
        Component: <Step2 />
      },
      {
        name: 'Step 3',
        Component: <Step3 />
      },
      {
        name: 'Step 4',
        Component: <Step4 />
      }
    ]

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0); // setting the state to 0
  const handleIndex = val => setActiveIndex(val);

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.contentBox}>
        <h3 className={classes.heading}>Heading</h3>
        <p className={classes.paragraph}>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes.breadcrumbs}>
          <Breadcrumbs separator=">" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            {switchArray.map((item, index) => (
                <Link
                  key={index}
                  className={classes.link}
                  color="inherit"
                  onClick={() => handleIndex(index)}
                  style={{color: index === activeIndex ? 'black' : 'inherit'}}
                >
                {item.name}
                </Link>

            ))}
          </Breadcrumbs>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.component}>{switchArray[activeIndex].Component}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you're looking for an overall review of a working piece of code, you may wish to consider posting this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This site is tailored towards answers specific questions about languages, programming, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Instead of using array, Object makes it easy.

2) Avoid using `index` for React component `key` value

```
const steps = {
  "Step 1": <Step1 />,
  "Step 2": <Step2 />,
  "Step 3": <Step3 />,
  "Step 4": <Step4 />
};

const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("Step 1");

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.contentBox}>
        <h3 className={classes.heading}>Heading</h3>
        <p className={classes.paragraph}></p>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes.breadcrumbs}>
          <Breadcrumbs separator=">" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            {Object.keys(steps).map(item => (
              <Link
                key={item}
                className={classes.link}
                color="inherit"
                onClick={() => setActiveItem(item)}
                style={{ color: item === activeItem ? "black" : "inherit" }}
              >
                {item}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </Breadcrumbs>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.component}>{steps[activeItem]}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```